# How can i put hover to the element in side bar?

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover, bootstrap-5

I want to put hover into the element inside the sidebar that I already have.
I try to use  hover ,but it seems not working. I appreciate every answer.

```css
.sidebar .navbar .nav-link:hover{
  color: #EFDBFF;
  display: block;
  background: white;
  border-color: #EFDBFF;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<header class="header row ">
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
    <div id="logo" class="pb-2 ps-2 pe-0 col-2">
      <img class="float-start py-2 ps-2 pe-2" src="assets/img/unknown.png">
      <a href="#" class="sidebar-toggler flex-shrink-0" id="menu-toggle">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-angle-left py-4 pe-2"></i>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
<div class="body row ">
  <div class="sidebar col-2 " id="sidebar">
    <!--sidebar start-->
    <div class="navbar-nav w-100">
      <div class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-laptop me-2"></i>Admin</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu bg-transparent border-0">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">A</a>
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">B</a>
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">C</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link"><i class="fa fa-th me-2"></i>Cập nhật PO</a>
      <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link"><i class="fa fa-keyboard me-2"></i>Phân loại PO</a>
      <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link"><i class="fa fa-chart-bar me-2"></i>Ước tính rebate</a>
      <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link"><i class="fa fa-tachometer-alt me-2"></i>Cập nhật rebate</a>
      <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link"><i class="fa fa-tachometer-alt me-2"></i>Báo cáo</a>
      <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link"><i class="fa fa-tachometer-alt me-2"></i>Tra cứu thông tin</a>
      <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link"><i class="fa fa-tachometer-alt me-2"></i>Hướng dẫn sử dụng</a>
    </div>
    <!--sidebar end-->
  </div>
  <div class="content col-10"> Content
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/60bf89e922.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: `.sidebar .navbar` does not exist.

Comment: in style tag change this `.sidebar .navbar .nav-link:hover` to `.sidebar .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover{ ...`

Comment: Your CSS selector should be 
```.sidebar .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover```

Comment: my god 
it all because of my stupidness
thankyou guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your css selector is wrong
this will solve your problem

```
.sidebar .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover{
  color: #EFDBFF;
  display: block;
  background: white;
  border-color: #EFDBFF;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your css code connected to html?

Maybe `nav-item` class overrides. Use `nav-link` class with `!important`

More information: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_important.asp

Answer (score 0):

I see your selector is incorrect.

On your html you have `navbar-nav` so you'll have to use .navbar-nav on your selector.

your html

```
...
    <!--sidebar start-->
    <div class="navbar-nav w-100">
...
```

so the updated selector is
`.sidebar .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover`

```
.sidebar .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover{
  color: #EFDBFF;
  display: block;
  background: white;
  border-color: #EFDBFF;
}
```

That will solve the problem.